# SQL combine AVG and RANK

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query

```
VariableWastage
          AS ( SELECT   ID ,
                        SCRAPVAR ,
                        COUNT(RECCODE) AS [COUNT] ,
                        RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY COUNT(RECCODE) DESC ) AS [RANK]
               FROM     RECIPE
               WHERE    ITEMTYPE != 2
                        AND CAST(CAST(SCRAPVAR AS FLOAT) AS INT) != 0 -- excluding SCRAPVAR 0
GROUP BY                ID ,
                        SCRAPVAR
             )SELECT * FROM VariableWastage
```

which gives results

[image]

Where rows are highlighted how do I produce one row per item and get the AVG SCRAPVAR values between the duplicates?  So basically in result set I would expect to see

```
ABR001    1.025
ABR002    1.025
ABR003    1.025
```

I just want to AVG the RANK output basically... Thanks!

Comment: So you want to filter your current result set to get the 3 records you have shown?

Comment: Just three records or all records?

Comment: I want all results, but where i'm getting duplicates combine them and avg the scrapvar result between the dupes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer... just do the AVG in the group by...

```
VariableWastage
               AS ( SELECT   ID ,
                             SCRAPVAR ,
                             COUNT(RECCODE) AS [COUNT] ,
                             RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY COUNT(RECCODE) DESC ) AS [RANK]
                    FROM     RECIPE
                    WHERE    ITEMTYPE != 2
                             AND CAST(CAST(SCRAPVAR AS FLOAT) AS INT) != 0 -- excluding SCRAPVAR 0
     GROUP BY                ID ,
                             SCRAPVAR
                  )SELECT ID, AVG(CAST(SCRAPVAR AS DECIMAL(4, 2))) as SCRAPVAR, COUNT, RANK   FROM VariableWastage GROUP BY ID, COUNT, RANK
```